# Как убрать ключи массива у которых только все значения пустые

Tags: php, массивы

Получаю на выходе такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Тест 1
            [keywords] => 111
            [description] => 111
            [artikul] => 1111
            [content] => Привет 1
            [price] => 555
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [description] => 
            [artikul] => 
            [content] => 
            [price] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [description] => 
            [artikul] => 
            [content] => 
            [price] => 
        )
)
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как в итоге можно обрезать те ключи, только у которых значения все пустые. Если хоть одно заполнено, обрезать не нужно.

Использовал библиотеку phpexel для импорта товаров в базу данных. Но почему то у которых строк в документе exel изменил высоту, но при этом они пустые, они тоже попадают в массив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
$input = [
    ['foo' => '', 'bar' => ''],
    ['foo' => '', 'bar' => '1'],
    ['foo' => '12', 'bar' => ''],
];

$output = array_filter($input, function($item) {
    foreach ($item as $value) {
        if ('' !== $value && null !== $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});

var_dump($output);
```

Используется функция [array_filter](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), где в callback-функции выполняется цикл по всем значениям каждого вложенного подмассива.

Comment: Помогло, отлично! Спасибо большое:) А Вы может знаете с чем такая проблема связана, что если у пустой строки в exel изменить высоту, то она тоже попадает в массив.

Comment: Нет, не работал плотно с excel

Comment: @Дмитрий, возможно, вам стоит сформулировать [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), в качестве контекста можете указать ссылку сюда.

Comment: @mymedia Позже создам. Дам знать.